# Converting a list(map(list(map(string)))) into a map(list(map(string))) with terraform

Tags: terraform

Hi there is there any neat way to convert a list(map(list(map(string)))) into a map(list(map(string))) with terraform .

Here's what my input structure looks like

```
`variable "data" {
  type = list(map(list(map(string))))
  default = [
    {
      secrets = [
        {
          secret-name   = "secret1"
          secret-label  = "label1"
        },
        {
          secret-name   = "secret2"
          secret-label  = "label2"
        }
      ],
      config-maps = [
        {
          config-map-name =  "conf1"
          java-options    = "-Xmx256m"
          config-label    = "develop"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      secrets = [
        {
          secret-name   = "secret3"
          secret-label  = "label3"
        }
      ],
      config-maps = [
        {
          config-map-name =  "conf2"
          java-options = "-Xmx256m"
          config-label = "develop"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}`
```

and here's what i want it to look like

```
`data = {
        secrets     = [
                        {
                          secret-name   = "secret1"
                          secret-label  = "label1"
                        },
                        {
                          secret-name   = "secret2"
                          secret-label  = "label2"
                        },
                        {
                          secret-name   = "secret3"
                          secret-label  = "label3"
                        },
                      ],
        config-maps = [
                        {
                          config-map-name =  "conf1"
                          java-options    = "-Xmx256m"
                          config-label    = "develop"
                        },
                        {
                          config-map-name =  "conf2"
                          java-options = "-Xmx256m"
                          config-label = "develop"
                        }
                      ]
      }
```

Can you guys help me achieve this please ? 
Ps : preferably in the locals part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then, how about this?

```
locals {
  values = flatten([
    for d in var.data : [
      for _, v in d : v
    ]
  ])
  keys = flatten([
    for d in var.data : [
      for k, v in d : [
        for _ in v : k
      ]
    ]
  ])
}

output data {
  value = {
    for k in distinct(local.keys) :
    k => matchkeys(local.values, local.keys, [k])
  }
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Hey can the output structure be typed ?                                                                                 for example :   variable "secret-data" {
  type   = list(object({
    secret-name  = string
    secret-label = string
    username  = number
    password= number
  }))
}

Comment: you can just define the type as `map(list(map(string)))`.